# Android check box button style for API < 21

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, android-styles

I added a style for a checkbox like below

```
<style name="SurveyCheckBox" >
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
</style>
```

It works perfectly but I also added this style for checkboxes created dynamically in a recycler view. In this case, style does not affect checkboxes. To solve this problem, I added "android:" before the item name.

```
<style name="SurveyCheckBox" >
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
</style>
```

This property works in API >=21 but does not work <21. Is there any solution for this problem?

**recycler_view_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/survey_check_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:textColor="@color/colorOnBackground"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/survey_check_box"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:theme="@style/SurveyCheckBox" /> </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox` instead of `CheckBox` ?

Comment: I also set parent value of style as "Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar" in addition to your answer then it worked. Thanks bro